# How to change jquery mobile a href button image?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Basically jquery mobile button is a normal rectangular shape,I want to change to use my own image to replace it.Got any refer on this topic?Below code is wrong example but can take as refer what i want.

example will shown normal button:

```
<a data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-transition="fade" data-theme="e"  data-icon="back" data-iconpos="left">
```

i try demo to replace it:

(HTML)

```
<a data-role="button" data-rel="back"  data-theme="app-ios">
```

(CSS)

```
/*button background and borders color */
a[data-theme="app-ios"] {
border: none;
width:80px;
}
a[data-theme="app-ios"] .ui-btn-corner-all {
border: none;
background:url('images/back.png') no-repeat 15px;
/*background:red;*/
border-radius:0; 
overflow: visible;
padding-left: 8px !important;
padding-right: 8px !important;
} 

/* shadows and label color */
a[data-theme="app-ios"].ui-shadow,
a[data-theme="app-ios"] {
box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none;
background-clip: none; -webkit-background-clip: none; -moz-background-clip: none;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
top: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This-Change the class ui-btn-corner-all into

```
.ui-btn-corner-all {
    -moz-border-radius:    5px
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px
    border-radius:         5px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a class to it and style the class...

HTML:

```
<a data-role="button" data-rel="back"  data-theme="app-ios" class="button">Button</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
​.button { color: #f0f; }​
```